# Excel: Aggregating two column sets into one

Tags: microsoft-excel

In one Excel sheet, I have two different data sets of three columns each, that represent very similar data.

I would like to combine this into one set of three columns.

Each data set has its leftmost column as the key I would like to group by.

A key appears once or never in each dataset. The other columns are numeric, and may be empty (interpreted as zero). The two series may be of different lengths.

Like so:

```
[Name_A],[Score_A],[Value_A],[Name_B],[Score_B],[Value_B]
Adam,14,20,Johnny,8,
Johnny,11,,Bernice,5,5
,,,Adam,2,8
```

should aggregate into:

```
[Name],[Score],[Value]
Adam,16,28
Johnny,19,
Bernice,5,5
```

The order of the rows in the final result is not important.

Answer (score 1):

Parse your data using text to columns and using the comma as a delimiter. Then compile a list of distinct names( You can do that using remove duplicates in the data tab in Excel.) and use `=sumif(Name_Column,Name1,Value1_Column)`.

This should sum everything up by name and value.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1):

The key to merging your datasets is to extract a list of the unique names.  This is **much** easier if the names are all in one column.  If you must have your data arranged as you've shown, there is a VBA solution, so comment below if you need that.

In the first table below, I've moved your "B" data under the "A" data, and added a few more rows in each section.

[image]

This formula, filled down from E2, lists the names and removes duplicates:

`=IFERROR(INDEX((A$2:A$15),MATCH(0,COUNTIF($E$1:E1,A$2:A$15),0)),"")`

It is an array formula, so it must be entered with <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>.

These two formulas, filled down from F2 and G2, add up the Score and Value for each name in the list:

`=IF(LEN(E2)<1,"",SUMIF(A$2:A$15,E2,B$2:B$15))`

`=IF(LEN(E2)<1,"",SUMIF(A$2:A$15,E2,C$2:C$15))`
 **______________________________________________________________________**

**How it works:** The inner `COUNTIF()` creates an array of the number of times each of the names in column A appear in the growing list in column E. The `MATCH()` finds the position of the first 0 (corresponding to a name that hasn't been listed yet) in that array, and that is used as the row_num in an `INDEX()`, which picks the name out of column A. Names which have already been listed do not appear again.

The `IFERROR()` inserts blanks for rows that would have a #NUM! error when the formula runs out of unique values.

The two `SUMIF()` formulas just add up the Score and Value numbers for each name.  The `IF()` inserts a blank for rows where the length of column E is < 1 (i.e. the cell has no name and appears blank).